# How to run a Apache Tomcat Webserver on my PC and access if from a real Android Device?

Tags: android, ip, tomcat7

I have a Tomcat 7.0 server running on my PC, I access the servlet via Emulator through  Url

```
http://10.0.2.2:8084/MyServer
```

I am struggling with this for few hours now. I have understood the following steps to achieve this

1. I need to have a Static IP address? So I am using `No-IP Free` to covert dynamic IP (I have a dial-up connection) to Static IP.
2. I need to change the firewall rules in Windows 7. I tried changing `Inbound Rules` for `'port 8084'`, but it did not work.

*My Question is how to access the same server on my PC via a real Android device having GPRS connection?*

Thanks so much.

Comment: what languages did you use to develop the application?

Comment: Java on the Server side.

Comment: can i do as you did without router please URGENT!

Comment: @shareef Better way to do this use Amazon EC2 it is free for an year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firewall rules on your Windows PC and wired/wireless router will both need to allow incoming connections to port 8084.

On the router, set up incoming connections to 8084 to redirect to your Windows PC's local IP address (`127.0.0.1`). This is called "port forwarding" – look into your router's manual on how to do it.

Once your router forwards incoming port 8084 requests to your Windows machine, you can access it from the outside:

```
http://your-dynamic-address.com:8084/MyServer
```

Answer (score 3):

wifi is the best answer. Get your machine and phone on the same network. If that isn't an option, I'd suggest local tunnel: http://progrium.com/localtunnel/

Comment: Thanks. I was trying the other answer. The documentation talks about **Ruby or RubyGems**. I am Java guy, may need some help to go about it.

Answer (score 1):

As long as your server has a public IP address, you'll be fine. The first you should try is to access it from your device using the *known* IP address and then go for the name resolution, for which DynDNS or No-IP Free will be valid options.

Let's say your pablic IP at any given time is `1.2.3.4`, just try

```
http://1.2.3.4:8084/MyServer
```

and it should work. Then configure any of the mentioned services and try using the host and domain name.

Comment: I was trying to set-up No-IP Free but could not access my PC. Then I read your answer. Can you explain What do you mean by **As long as your server has public IP Adress.** I am talking about a dial-up connection on my PC.

Comment: I meant as long as your dial-up gives you a public address and doesn't sit behind a NAT service

Comment: Ok, so I found on web that private IP are in range 10.x.x.x, 172.16.x.x, 192.168.x.x but my IP is not in this range therefore it is Public.