# How to access my application running on tomcat server using IP address instead of localhost

Tags: tomcat, ip

I am trying to access my web application deployed in tomcat server using IP address instead of 
localhost. I am trying to access the address from the same PC where the application was deployed. Interestingly, it worked for me at my work wi-fi network but not in my home network. I have already seen

[How to run a Apache Tomcat Webserver on my PC and access if from a real Android Device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636430/how-to-run-a-apache-tomcat-webserver-on-my-pc-and-access-if-from-a-real-android)

[why tomcat instance running by tomcat is only visible with localhost address not with my real network ip?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13307429/why-tomcat-instance-running-by-tomcat-is-only-visible-with-localhost-address-not)

Does this have something to do with my firewall settings or router settings. If so can someone provide detailed pointers on what has to be done?

Comment: When you say you're using the IP address of your home-PC, I assume you mean the IP that your ISP has assigned you (not 192.168.x.x.). If that is right, then certain ports may not be accessible. Check your router's admin app, looking for "port forwarding".

Comment: @Darius: I meant the 192.168.x.x. only

Comment: In server.xml, on your connector, do you have address="localhost" or something like that? If so, remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

In the File configuration **Httpd.conf** of Apache the line that serves (File of Connector) to Tomcat (Suppose in Windows):

```
Include ".../Tomcat/conf/auto/mod_jk.conf"
```

In the file **mod_jk.conf** maybe you have:

```
...
JkWorkersFile "...LocationOfYourWorkerFile..."
...
<VirtualHost localhost>
  ...
  ServerName localhost
  ...
  JkMount /*.jsp ajp13
</VirtualHost>
```

Where **ajp13** is Tomcat worker defined in JkWorkersFile.

In the **JkWorkersFile** maybe you have:

```
worker.list=ajp13
worker.ajp13.port=8009
worker.ajp13.host=localhost
worker.ajp13.type=ajp13
# END workers.properties
```

Change to in **mod_jk.conf** file:

```
<VirtualHost  *:80>
  ...
  ServerName localhost
  ...
  JkMount /*.jsp ajp13
</VirtualHost>
```

In this case you are saying that not only works for localhost, but also works for all ip's through 80 port.